# Trouble with integrating Play Game Services (can't find a specific version of android support library)

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am trying to integrate the Google Play Game Services with my project. I have added the play services as a dependency to my build.gradle, but when I try to rebuild the project I get this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':android'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':android:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1.
     Required by:
         Taxi Trouble:android:1.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

According to the SDK manager I have version 19.1, instead of the required 19.0.1. Can I install this older version of the support library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please share your build.gradle file.  The following example, taken from an update to the Play-[Google Play Games Services GitHub pages](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples), shows a working build.gradle file with the latest support library.

First, note that there are multiple build.gradle files and settings.gradle files in a particular project/workspace. Let's focus on the two most likely candidates for breaking your build.

1. root (build.gradle) (e.g. root/build.gradle)
2. Android module for your app (e.g. root/module/build.gradle)

Root project **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

**build.gradle** from within a project module:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
        //compile project(':libraries:BaseGameUtils')
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    repositories {
    }
}
```

It's a little confusing at first but your gradle build library version must match your ADT version which must match your GMS version. As Android Studio stabilizes, required updates to match configurations across tools and Android libraries will hopefully become less common.